# Django action on admin.ModelAdmin.save_model()

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I need collect the info that the user introduce to the form, and then sent to a server, I am using sockets.

I am not talking about Validators or admin actions, the data will be saved, but when it save, I need what is on the paragraph that I wrote is above.

I can sent the data, but if the server is not active or not reachable, I want to warn the user that the action can not be finished.

How can I do this ?

Again, the data must be saved.

Do you understand me?

EDIT:

it means  data should input and entered data will be saved ,and if server is down users will be informed with server down message.

Comment: "Do you understand me?" sorry to say, no!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is what I did:

Override save_model()

```
from client.exceptions import PrintServerError  # this is my own Exception
super(MyModelAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)  # Save object
instruction = Instruction.objects.get(name='print_client_label')  # This model has the server information
    request.POST['instruction'] = instruction
    request.POST['accessory'] = obj
client = Client(server=instruction.printer.server.ip, instruction=instruction.name,
                          username=request.user.id, sn=obj.serial_number.serial_number)  # Client that connects to the server
    if not client.main():  # If an error ocurred, Raise a exception
        raise PrintServerError(client.error)
```

Then I create a Middleware, for handling exceptions.

Added it into settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
...
'common.middleware.MyMiddleware')
```

MyMiddleware code:

```
class MyMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        # Error on app, when trying to connect to the label printer server
        if type(exception) in (error, PrintServerError):
            instruction = request.POST['instruction']
            context = {
                'host': instruction.printer.server.name,
                'ip': instruction.printer.server.ip,
                'template_error': exception.message  # template_error, means template that is used for a label, no Django template
            }
            return render(request, 'myapp/printer_server_error.html', context=context)
        return None
```

And the template code:

```
{% if not template_error %}
<p>
    El servidor de impresión de etiquetado no responde.<br>
    <br>
    Por favor verifique la configuración de las IP de la maquina conectada a las impresoras y que esta misma, tenga
    conexión a internet.<br>
    <br>
    Información del error:<br>
    <br>
    Nombre del servidor de impresión: <strong>{{ host }}</strong><br>
    Ip del servidor impresión: <strong>{{ ip }}</strong>
    <br>
    <strong>No se ha guardado el cambio.</strong>
</p>
{% else %}
    <p>
    {{ template_error }}
    </p>
{% endif %}
```

So, this can save the data, send the data to a server, and if an error ocurred, the user will be warned.